# Linq to Sql : Overwrite properties while Joining tables

Tags: c#, linq, join

I'm trying to overwrite an object by values of another table depending the culture.  I would like to keep the original object-type.  I already tried different approach but always ending up with a non-supported-exception or a casting error.

Example Code:

What I wanted to retrieve is the original object with "Name" and the "Text" overwritten by the Contact_tls table like

1. this will return me a list of the original Contacts, not translated.
2. this will return me a list of translated items as I want but as an Anonymous typelist.
3. Possible, but you have to re-assign all non-language related properties like (ID's, ApplicationID, PhoneNumber, etc)
4. Last approach, It should be something similar ( throwing errors )

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       List Contacts = new List();
       webDataContext db = new webDataContext();

   ```
   //1
   Contacts = db.Contacts.Join(
       db.Contact_tls.Where(i => i.Culture == "fr"),
       i => i.ID,
       t => t.ID,
       (i, t) => i).ToList();

   //2
   var linqObject = db.Contacts.Join(
       db.Contact_tls.Where(i => i.Culture == "fr"),
       i => i.ID,
       t => t.ID,
       (i, t) => new { ID = i.ID, Name = t.Name, Text = t.Text }).ToList();

   //3
   Contacts = db.Contacts.Join(
       db.Contact_tls.Where(i => i.Culture == "fr"),
       i => i.ID,
       t => t.ID,
       (i, t) => new Contact { ID = i.ID, Name = t.Name, Text = t.Text }).ToList();

   //4  
   var contacts = db.Contacts.Join(
       db.Contact_tls.Where(i => i.Culture == "fr"),
       i => i.ID,
       t => t.ID,
       (i, t) => i { Name = t.Name, Text = t.Text }).ToList();
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

I would create the Class using Linq to Objects, so you could modify #2 as follows:

```
Contacts = db.Contacts.Join(
    db.Contact_tls.Where(i => i.Culture == "fr"),
    i => i.ID,
    t => t.ID,
    (i, t) => new { ID = i.ID, Name = t.Name, Text = t.Text })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x =>  new Contact { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name, Text = x.Text })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks,

Thats idd more like I was doing in Solution 3.  It's the way I go for the moment but with 30 different tables to translate it's still not the best way.

The most important issue in this solution is the requirmeent to update the code after each table-change (column-changes).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a constructor to the `Contract` class with a parameter per property and use it with number 3:

```
Contacts = db.Contacts.Join(db.Contact_tls.Where(i => i.Culture == "fr"),
                            i => i.ID, t => t.ID,
                            (i, t) => new Contact(i.ID, t.Name, t.Text))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the response!

'Contact' is a auto-generated class by using a .dbml file (Linq to SQL Classes), so it's not possible to add a constructor.

Otherwise, An override method that automatically overrides all value of the translation tabel having an equal column name.